# How to create a generic higher order function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm not sure how I can create a function that generically adds behavior to another function. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
/**
 * Creates a function that calls originalFunction, followed by newFunction.
 * The created function returns the value returned by the original function
 * returned by the original function
 * @param originalFunction Function to be called first
 * @param newFunction Function to be called second
 */
function callAfter<T extends Function>(originalFunction: T, newFunction: T): any {
   return function() {
        const result = originalFunction.apply(this, arguments);
        newFunction.apply(this, arguments);
        return result;
   };
}
```

The above doesn't compile with the following message

> TS2322: Type '() => any' is not assignable to type 'T'

Is there anything I can do to keep type safety? For now I have it "working" by making it return `any`

I tried it a bit further and came up with the following

```
/**
 * Creates a function that calls originalFunction, followed by newFunction. The created function returns the value
 * returned by the original function
 * @param originalFunction Function to be called first
 * @param newFunction Funct
 */
function callAfter<R, T extends () => R>(originalFunction: T, newFunction: T): T {
    return <T> function () {
        const result: R = originalFunction.apply(this, arguments);
        newFunction.apply(this, arguments);
        return result;
    };
}
```

The problem with this one is that it doesn't work for functions that return void (which was the use case I actually cared about at the moment)

This is the code I'm trying to write but would like to use a generic higher order function to extend functionality.

```
/**
 * Component can use this to have subscriptions automatically
 * removed when the component is removed from the DOM
 */
class SubscriptionTracker {
    private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

    constructor(destroyable: OnDestroy) {
        destroyable.ngOnDestroy = callAfter(destroyable.ngOnDestroy, () => {
            this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription) => subscription.unsubscribe());
        });
    }

    subscribe<T>(observable: Observable<T>, observer: PartialObserver<T>): Subscription {
        const subscription = observable.subscribe(observer);
        this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
        return subscription;
    }

    unsubscribe(subscription: Subscription) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        const indexOfSubscription = this.subscriptions.indexOf(subscription);
        if (indexOfSubscription == -1) {
            throw new Error('Unsubscribing to untracked subscription');
        }
        this.subscriptions.splice(indexOfSubscription, 1);
        return subscription;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question, you just need better constraints over the return type and arguments. Rather than making the functor take two functions of the same type `T`, we can define a proper function type to each.

```
function callAfter<O>(f: (...any) => O, f2: (...any) => void): (...any) => O {
    return (...args) => {
        let r = f(...args);
        f2(...args);
        return r;
    }
}
```

A few examples:

```
function  double(x) { return x + x; };

function yell(x) {
    console.log(`${x}!!!`);
}

let doubleLoud = callAfter(double, yell);
let x = doubleLoud(4501);
console.log(`doubleLoud(4501) = ${x}`);
```

It also works with functions returning void on any side, or even functions with multiple arguments:

```
callAfter(yell, yell)("Ni");

let lreluLoud = callAfter(function lrelu(x, alpha) {
    if (x < 0) x *= alpha;
    return x;
}, yell);

console.log(`lreluLoud(-20, 0.2) = ${lreluLoud(-20, 0.2)}`);
```

Comment: Well, I want the compiler to make sure both functions passed in are the same type.
This doesn't work for something that does return a type, also doesn't do type checking of arguments... I know I may be asking for too much... but the one I suggested does more type checking than the one you suggested?

Comment: Well, technically the second function would not need to be the same type. Other than that, I understand your concern, my attempts over here suggest that the current compiler can only go so far. Maybe it's time to look into the issue tracker.

Comment: I think it does need to be the same type, because I'm going to call it the exact the same way as the first.

Comment: On the other hand, you are not using the returned value of the second. Therefore, the return type of the second argument function should be `void` by convention.